# Why is frequency of a sine signal is equal to its "rate of change of phase"?

Tags: analog, signal-processing

I want to learn more about PLL but I'm stuck with the concept of "rate of change of phase" which is said that is equal to frequency. At the moment I'm very ignorant at the topic so I need to understand this mathematical foundation before I can proceed.

I couldn't decide whether this is a math question or can also belong here since its about analog signal. Is there an easy way to relate the phase to frequency? How is frequency equal to the rate of change of phase and isn't the phase of a sine fixed always given a sinusoid? So is this about signals where their phases changing by time? I could find any easy derivation on the topic.

Comment: A reference to where you're reading about these concepts from would be useful.

Comment: The phase is a vector in the complex plane of the signal frequency. If the phase changes, this vector spins with the frequency of its rate change.

Comment: @Janka ehm, the phase is an angle, not a vector ;)

Comment: if the rate of change of phase is 360 degrees per second, you have one full sinwave per second. You can also write this as 2*PI radians per second. Radians is more common. Many equations in electronics use radians to express the solutions of the underlying differential equations that encapsulate the movement of energy between various reactances and/or dissipative elements. To express the solutions in cycles/second (aka Hertz since about 1965), we insert 2*pi in those equations.

Comment: @carloc: How do you spin an angle? Yes, it's just another complication in your mind serving no purpose in this context.

Comment: @Janka you may call it as you like, nonetheless even if it sounds complicated to you, an apple is still an apple, and a phase is an angle to everybody but you

Answer (score 5):

If you're like me, you grew up memorizing an equation similar to \$sin(2\pi ft+\phi)\$, where \$2\pi\$ is a single cycle of a sinusoid, \$f\$ is the frequency that the sinusoid oscillates at measured in \$cycles\over second\$ (even though it should be \$1\over second\$ if you think about it, but more on that later), \$t\$ is time, and \$\phi\$ is initial phase in \$radians\$. Though this memorization works for constant frequency sinusoids, it doesn't help much when the frequency is variable. In that case it's better to think of it simply as \$sin(\phi)\$, where \$\phi\$ isn't initial phase, it's just phase generally, like how in \$sin(x)\$ \$x\$ is just some angle. \$\phi\$ can be a constant or any function, and ***the rate that \$\phi\$ changes is equal to the frequency that the sinusoid oscillates at***. Let's look at a few examples.

- In the case that \$\phi\$ is a constant: \$sin(constant) = constant\$. Therefore \$frequency = 0\$ because the sinusoid doesn't oscillate. Also, the derivative, or rate of change, of a constant is 0. So \$f={d\phi \over dt}=constant'=0\$ holds.
- In the case that \$\phi\$ is a linear function of time like \$2\pi at\$ (\$a\$ is a constant): \$sin(\phi) = sin(2\pi at)\$, which, as you know, is a constant frequency sinusoid with frequency of \$a\$. \$f={d\phi \over dt}=(2\pi at)'=2\pi a=a {cycles \over second}\$.
- In the case that \$\phi\$ is a quadratic function of time like \$2\pi at^2\$ (\$a\$ again is a constant): \$sin(\phi) = sin(2\pi at^2)\$, which is a sinusoid who's frequency increases with time. Think of a slinky that becomes more compressed the further along it's length you look. Now, here's the kicker. \$f={d\phi \over dt}=(2\pi at^2)'=2\pi *2at=2at {cycles \over second}\$.

In the last example, if you would've followed your intuition from your childhood math class, you would've simply deduced that frequency is equal to \$at\$ not \$2at\$ because that intuition doesn't take the rate of change into account. And, to go full circle, the reason the typical sinusoidal representation works is because \$f\$ is a constant making \$\phi =2\pi ft\$ linear and the derivative of a linear function is the constant in front of it, in this case \$f\$.

So, in summation, phase isn't the initial phase \$\phi\$ you remember. Phase, more generally, is the position in the cycle of the sinusoid. And the frequency of that sinusoid is defined as the rate of change of it's phase.

Answer (score 3):

They're not equal *because* of anything, they are equal by definition.

We often write a sinewave as as function of time as \$v = \sin(\omega t)\$

Every time the argument \$\omega t\$ increases by \$2\pi\$, then \$v\$ comes back to what it was before, defining one cycle of the sinewave. \$\omega\$ is known as the *angular frequency*, in radians per second.

Radians are convenient mathematically, but inconvenient to human brains, so another common way we see it written is \$v = \sin(2\pi ft)\$, where \$f\$ is the frequency in Hertz, what used to be known as cycles per second.

Of course with a sine function, the argument is an angle. Electrical engineering is so much simplified by using complex representation instead of sine and cosine, that it borrows the word *phase* from complex analysis, often talking about phase angle, or simply phase.

Comment: This. Exact. Thing! Understanding we *define* frequency as the derivative of phase is paramount to people getting concepts like a PLL fixing a frequency offset.

Comment: Something is not clear about this. I still dont understand. They define w*t as phi and then there is another phi which is the phase many knows. so there are two phi here. one is called instantaneous phase which contributes so much confusion. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0120/00f1253c2261cc994c7fbedaf6d8a650ac36.pdf I cannot find a clear step by step derivation.

Comment: @atmnt - that is not the best article to resolve your confusion since it adds the complication of modulation. Try this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instantaneous_phase_and_frequency

Comment: @Mattman944 It's one of those articles that's completely true, but not necessarily very helpful. It's such a simple concept that it needs an Aha! moment, probably best got by playing with Matlab or similar.

Answer (score 2):

A sine wave can have a *relative* phase to another sine of the same frequency or be described as having a specific phase at *time zero*. This is not the type of phase they are discussing here.

They are referring to an *instantaneous* phase. The frequency is the derivative of the phase, ω = dθ / dt. All units are rads, of course.

Comment: I'm not sure these are two different types of phase. Just one is referenced to itself-in-the-past instead of to some other reference signal.

Answer (score 1):

Frequency is related to rate of phase change in a same way than the speed of a car is related to rate of change of its position.

Answer (score 0):

Phase can be measured in many units. Volts, radians, degrees and converted by some constant for some application.

Consider 3600 rev per minute

3600 RPM = 3600 revs * 360 deg / 60 s = 3600 * 6 deg/s

Next consider for each 1 Hz of difference frequency there is a slew rate change of  360 deg per cycle per second.

When a PLL mixer uses a phase detector to measure the difference between two frequencies,  the transfer function is **Kp/s** is an integrator.

They do have type II phase/frequency detectors which you can read about in the CD4066 datasheet.

As frequency is the rate of change or partial derivative of phase, the  inverse being phase difference is now the integral (1/s) of frequency error.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing yourself because you're missing the key word:  'rate'.

It has nothing to do with the specific angle, but rather has to do with the rate of change per second-  frequency is a function of change over time.  If you go from one level of voltage or current, to another level of voltage or current, and you do that repeatedly, then the number of times you do that per second, is the rate.  By definition, if it's repeated, then the angle at any point along the sinusoid will be repeated every cycle.

Grasp that, then go read about phasors and vectors in A/C mathematics for determining voltage or current at a given phase angle.